# Please help me to Marshal this array of structs to C++

Tags: c++, marshalling, com-interop

The C++ code:

```
  typedef struct {
    int bd_number;                      // number of boardset
    int bd_copies;                      // how many copies
    int bd_reserve;                     // only allocate if needed
} bd_t,*bd_p;

typedef struct boardset_info {
    int     bs_copies;          
    int     bs_demand;          
    int     bs_allocated;       
    int     bs_ontable_avail;       
    int     bs_ontable_needed;      
    pstatus bs_status;              
    int     bs_played_sofar;        
} bsi_t, *bsi_p;

FC_ERRORCODE dropin_boards(bd_p boards) {
    int bs;

    bs_info = (bsi_p) calloc(total_boardsets+1, sizeof(bsi_t));//total_boardsets=8
    for (bs = 1; bs <= total_boardsets; bs++)
        bs_info[bs].bs_status = PS_OUTPLAY;

    while (boards->bd_number) { //boards-<bd_number is betweeen 1 and 8
        if (boards->bd_number < 0 || boards->bd_number > total_boardsets)
        {
            debprint("***Error dropin_boards***\n");
            debprint("boardsetnumber=%d\n",boards->bd_number);
            return FC_ERR_PARAM;
        }
        //code does not reach this point
    }
```

Calling code:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure Flex_BoardSetInfo
    Public SetNumber As Integer
    Public Copies As Integer
    Public IsReserve As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("FlexCalc2.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Public Shared Function FlexCalcBoards(ByRef boards() As Flex_BoardSetInfo) As Flex_ErrorCode
    End Function

Dim boardsets() = GetBoardSetInfo() // creates an arry of 8 BoardsetInfo Elements

_result = FlexCalcWrapper.FlexCalcBoards(boardsets)
```

On the last line on the  debug file is logged that bd_p->board_number=517237496! The boardnumbers are initialized 1 to 8 and I can check that that has been correctly done before the code passes to the C++ dll.
How do I solve this?

EDIT:
From VB6 we used a hack to get this C++ method working:

```
Declare Function FlexCalcBoards Lib "FlexCalc2.dll" (firstBoard As BoardsetInfo)
ret=FlexCalcBoards(Boards(0))
```

So, we passed the first element of the array in stead of the array itself! (Un?)fortunately, Net does not fall for this trick...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What is the "debug file"?

Comment: @luke Look at the `debprint` statement: it writes to a debug file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answers and comments seemed to indicate that nothing should be wrong, so....
I found three things:
1. Even after rebuilding the entire solution and copying and pasting the new FlexCalc2.dll to the testproject, the old copy of the dll that resided in the Bin folders was NOT replaced.
2. I am a novice in C++, but it seems that you cannot iterate through an array using LBound to UBound when the method has only received a pointer to it. The method shown uses a nifty way to implement a kind of `for each`, but here it does not work because `bd_p->boardnumber` returns a very high number (memory address?), but `bd_p[index].boardnumber` returns the correct number within the range 1-8. I simply sent the length of the array as an extra parameter to the function and I was all set. (Call it the poor man's choice for all I care ;-))
3. Hans Passant was right in stating that when the method signature in C++ is `theReturnValue theMethod(theStruct * theArray)` that from Net you must pass the array `ByVal` (In VB6 this generates a syntax error and is not possible). The fact that a pointer to the array was passed is not immediately obvious since the `*` was already declared in the `typedef` of the struct.

Answer (score 2):

Replace ByRef with ByVal.  An array already gets marshaled as a pointer.

Using ByRef would only match a `bd_t**` on the C side.

Comment: It makes no difference now the value of BoardSetInfo.BoardSetNumber which has the value of 1 is extracted as board->board_number=451266504. So the C++ code reads the wrong memory address? See my additional info above.

Comment: You needed the VB6 hack because it also passed the array by reference.  No longer required since you now can pass it ByVal.  What else is wrong is impossible to tell from the snippet.  Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1 is a core debugging window to see what pointers are pointing at.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that? How do I debug this?